# Как убрать KeyboardButton в aiogram без отправки сообщения?

Tags: python, telegram, aiogram

Как убрать KeyboardButton в aiogram без отправки сообщения?
Есть такой способ - `await message.reply("Убираем шаблоны сообщений", reply_markup=kb.ReplyKeyboardRemove())`
И есть такой нерабочий `message.delete_reply_markup()`
Не предлагать способы с одним нажатием - `start_keyboard = ReplyKeyboardMarkup(one_time_keyboard=True)`
***P.S пустое сообщение или пробел отправить нельзя.***

Comment: без отправки сообщения вроде бы удалить нельзя, но как решение - ты можешь отправлять сообщение с любым текстом, указав в нем `reply_markup=kb.ReplyKeyboardRemove()` и следом `message.delete()` чтобы удалить отправленное сообщение